# Quiero asociar una computed properties a un vector pero me devuelve la longitud no el vector

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
    <section> 
        <div>
            {{vectorAdd}}
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script>

export default {

    data(){
        return {       
            vector:[]          
        }
    },


    computed:{
        VectorAdd(){
          return this.vector.push(7,9,5,5,5)            
        }
    }


}
</script>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tenes, es que exactamente estas haciendo eso.

El metodo push de js, devuelve el tamaño del arreglo, y no el arreglo en si.

No se como queres manejar tu clase computada, ni que estas tratando de hacer, porque eso no queda claro.

Pero en VUE, tu variable computada deberia (o se usa) para devolver un calculo entre varias propiedas.

Lo que vos estas haciendo, el push, se puede hacer en cualquier lado, y la variable va a reaccionar a eso.

Como nota, lo que te esta pasando se arreglaria de la siguiente forma:

```
computed:{
    VectorAdd(){
      this.vector.push(7,9,5,5,5);
      return this.vector;            
    }
}
```

Aunque, tene en cuenta que si en tu template, escribis `{{this.vector}}` vas a lograr el mismo resultado y no necesitarias computar la variable.